# AppEngine datastore reserve ID range

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to tell AppEngine Datastore to reserve a range of IDs, which should never be allocated to models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: `db.allocate_id_range(...)`

Comment: I have never  used it, but it catches my attention to speed up the creation of resources in my web-application

Comment: Michele, does it really speed up anything?

Comment: It's the correct answer to the question, but I'd be surprised if it sped up anything; it's an extra (small) db operation and an extra RPC roundtrip.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum, I agree. My intention of using the method was different: reserve the range so I can use it for something else.

Comment: well "speed up" in this sense: I mean that if a GUI request the creation of a resource, we can allocate an id (instead of persisting the resource), persist to memcache and return the control to the GUI. Then we can create the resource with an asynchronous call. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's actually somewhat similar to what I'm doing :-). In my case, I preallocate the IDs, then sync it with the server later. That's why I needed to reserve the ID range for local usage.